# Sitecore - Hide "Publish Subitems" from publish pop up

Tags: sitecore

I need to hide "Publish Subitems" from publish pop up? 
Since there are loads of content in my content hierarchy(More than 1Million), trying to publish an item with subitems will not going to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override `sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish\Publish.xml` form and disable or hided the `PublishChildren` checkbox:

```
<Checkbox ID="PublishChildren" Header="Publish Subitems"/>
```

Do not delete it as it will cause `NullReference` while publishing.

Here is some information about overriding Sitecore xml controls using `override` folder [Customize an XML Control](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Customize%20an%20XML%20Control.aspx)