# Sitecore - Publish subitems checkbox dynamically populating

Tags: sitecore

I have seen a post in Stackoverflow regarding how to hide the "Publish sub items" from Sitecore publish pop up by overriding the visibility of the checkbox. This is really good which can avoid so many performance issues when there is large amount of content in the content tree.

Is it possible to dynamically hide this checkbox? Coz, as a developer I need to publish other Sitecore items (Templates, Settings etc.) when it comes to deployments. Therefore "Publish sub items" is a essential feature for me. Still I need it to be hidden from content editors. 
How can I achieve this task? 
(If there was a security configuration to control access to this feature it would have been ideal)

Comment: Do you have the link to the other post? So we could have a look at the code and help you extending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to change Publish.xml file from Folder:

```
 \web\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish\
```

You need to change CodeBeside it will look like this :

```
   <WizardForm CodeBeside="YourNameSpace.CustomPublishForm,YourAssembly">
```

Your class will be :

```
class CustomPublishForm:PublishForm
{
    public CustomPublishForm()
        : base()
    {

    }
    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        //you need to change here with users that you want to see CheckBox
        if (Sitecore.Context.User.Name.Equals("lorenipsum"))
         {
            base.PublishChildren.Visible = true;
         }else
          {
            base.PublishChildren.Visible = false;
          }
     }
```

}

I tested and it's working fine this solution you have just to do minor changes to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted. But I'm just worried how I can deal these stuff with when it comes to Upgrades. Any plans for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the post: [Sitecore - Hide "Publish Subitems" from publish pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569951/sitecore-hide-publish-subitems-from-publish-pop-up)

You'll want to alter the `CodeBeside` attribute from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm,Sitecore.Client` to your own class that wraps that one. In your own class override any methods you need to in order for the logic to show or hide the box per your needs, e.g. user is in a certain role.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that such modifications make upgrades a bit harder. 
Copying the `Publish.xml` and triggering this from a new button makes it clear for everyone, that this is not Sitecore but your own logic.